# How to make Redis work from disk? Not about persistence

Tags: redis

There are chances I selected the wrong tool for this task, feel free to suggest if you know a better one.

The task: I need to store key-value pairs.

- Each pair is 60 bytes. The keys are IDs and values - both are pretty random or at least unstructured.
- There are ~2 milliards of such pairs which makes ~110 GB of pure data in total. Good chances for growth in the future.
- The write load is heavy, and the read one is rather light.
- It'd be nice to have a performance at 1K IOPS for writing, but maybe it's just a dream and I'll have to go with something slower but not so expensive.
- I can batch writing, but the keys won't be sequential (like `123,7,13565` instead of `1,2,3`)
- No fancy search is needed, just give the value for the complete key.
- I'm on AWS, if it matters, but can switch for a really good solution.
- Cost matters.

Redis is a key-value store, so I thought to use it but keeping such a big DB in memory is cost-prohibitive so I'd like to configure Redis in a way where it will take the data from memory as a cache, and when there's a cache miss - from the disk.

So, it is not about Redis's persistence as a backup.

Besides Redis I have tried:

- plain files in directory tree, like `key='abcdef' => ab/cd/ef`. Ext2, BtrFS, tried to distribute writes across 16 partitions (terrible performance after ~0.5M pairs)
- MySQL (silently died)

Also I thought about AWS Elasticache Redis with Data Tiering, but the cheapest instance has insane cost for me (~$600/mo)

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to make Redis work from disk?

You don't. It's primarily an In-Memory cache database.

> The task: I need to store key-value pairs.

Ok, simple and straightforward for any database system.

> There are ~2 milliards of such pairs which makes ~110 GB of pure data in total. Good chances for growth in the future.

Cool, 2 billion rows of data is a good amount, but any modern database system should be able to handle it fine. 110 GB of raw data size is quite manageable too.

> The write load is heavy, and the read one is rather light.

Ok, sounds like there won't be much concern with concurrent reads and writes then. Could you quantify the rate of which writing occurs (e.g. 1,000 rows per minute)?

> It'd be nice to have a performance at 1K IOPS for writing, but maybe it's just a dream and I'll have to go with something slower but not so expensive.

1K IOPS is not fast at all. Modern NVMe devices can achieve over 1 million IOPS. A cheap NVMe should achieve at least 100K IOPS.

> I'm on AWS, if it matters, but can switch for a really good solution.

Ah well that's where the cookie crumbles. Overpaying for under-provisioned hardware with hard limitations.

> Cost matters.

Avoid the cloud then and build your own server. It'll pay for itself in a few months or less.

> Redis is a key-value store, so I thought to use it but keeping such a big DB in memory is cost-prohibitive...

Yea it's not really meant to store such large amounts of data in Memory, at one time, reasonably speaking.

> Besides Redis I have tried:
>
> - plain files in directory tree, like key='abcdef' => ab/cd/ef. Ext2, BtrFS, tried to distribute writes across 16 partitions (terrible performance after ~0.5M pairs)

This is never the way. File directories are not database systems and not meant to manage data efficiently like database systems.

> - MySQL (silently died)

This could work. What happened here? What does "*silently died*" mean?

> Also I thought about AWS Elasticache Redis with Data Tiering, but the cheapest instance has insane cost for me (~$600/mo)

Nope, don't do that. This is just more In-Memory caching at a very premium price.

> How can I achieve that?

You can use any modern relational database management system (RDBMS) to handle your use case. It's simple, and reasonable in size. PostgreSQL would probably be your best bet for a free system. If you're willing to pay for enterprise software, then I personally prefer Microsoft SQL Server.

You can also use any modern key-value store database system. Since you're on AWS already, DynamoDB would be one of the main options there. You should thoroughly research any limitations of it should you go this route, as I feel like there might be some that make management a little bit of a work.

But if you're trying to minimize your costs while maximizing your performance, especially write IOPS, then you should really get off the cloud and just build your own server, as I mentioned earlier. It'll be significantly cheaper for hardware that's magnitudes faster. And any modern RDBMS would handle your use case just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. More details about my MySQL attempt: I tried to distribute data on multiple tables/columns (kind of sharding)  like abcdef =>ab(in table name)-cd(in column name). the daemon hunged up waiting for IO when I tried to create >5k tables having 256 columns each. Now I suspect it's a bad idea at all but would like to know your opinion - is it better to use one huge table for this case, maybe using native DB sharding?

Comment: @Putnik You definitely never want to reinvent the wheel on Sharding, and most people don't actually need Sharding to begin with. I don't know if you really need Sharding, especially because your read / write concurrency is low. I've managed tables in the 10s of billions of rows, multi-terabyte big, on basic hardware, that were write-heavy, without Sharding just fine. I would think you probably don't. I would also recommend trying PostgreSQL if you want to use a free RDBMS again (instead of MySQL). You probably would be fine with it.

Comment: Thank you, will do!